# Embedding an array into another

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have two arrays. The first one is a consecutive sequential one, like:

```
  seq1 =

 1     0
 2     0
 3     0
 4     0
 5     0
 6     0
 7     0
 8     0
 9     0
10     0 
...continues
```

The second one is like:

```
  seq2 =

 2   250
 3   260
 5   267
 6   270
 8   280
10   290
13   300
18   310
20   320
21   330 
...continues
```

I need to embed `seq2` into `seq1` in such a way that I end up with the sequence:

```
  seq3 =

 1     0
 2   250
 3   260
 4   260
 5   267
 6   270
 7   270
 8   280
 9   280
10   290
11   290
... continues
```

I could do this with loops but the arrays are really big so I don't want to use two `for` loops, it is taking too long. How can I do this in a vectorised manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
[~, jj, vv] = find(sum(bsxfun(@le, seq2(:,1), seq1(:,1).'), 1));
seq3 = seq1;
seq3(jj,2) = seq2(vv,2);
```

#### How it works

The required index is obtained by computing how many values in the first column of `seq2` are less than or equal to each value in the first column or `seq1` (code `sum(bsxfun(@le, ...), 1)`). This will be used to select the appropriate entries from the second column of `seq2` and write them into the result. But before that, the value `0` in this index needs to be discarded. This is done using the three-output version of `find` (code `[~, jj, vv] = find(...)`).

Answer (score 2):

If your second column of data is always increasing, you can solve this easily with [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) and [`cummax`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cummax.html):

```
seq = [seq1; seq2];
seq3 = cummax(accumarray(seq(:, 1), seq(:, 2), [], @max));
seq3 = [(1:numel(seq3)).' seq3];
```

And here's what you get for your sample inputs:

```
seq3 =

     1     0
     2   250
     3   260
     4   260
     5   267
     6   270
     7   270
     8   280
     9   280
    10   290
    11   290
    12   290
    13   300
    14   300
    15   300
    16   300
    17   300
    18   310
    19   310
    20   320
    21   330
```

### How it works...

After concatenating `seq1` and `seq2`, `accumarray` collects all the values in the second column that have the same value in the first column (i.e. `[0 250]` for the value `2`), then gets the [maximum value](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) of each set. The function `cummax` is then used to fill any zero values with the previous non-zero value. Finally, an index column is added to the new sequence.